Mocking a function import with from keyword
There are three files, a file with a test and two simple modules:
a.py:
import b

def bar():
    b.foo()

b.py:
def foo():
    print("Hello from b.py")

test_a.py:
from a import bar
from unittest import mock

def test_bar():
    with mock.patch('b.foo') as mock_foo:
        bar()
        mock_foo.assert_called_once()

The goal is to mock the function foo from the module b which is then called inside the function bar. The above code works as expected and the test will pass.
However, when the file a.py will be modified as follows, where the foo function is imported directly from the module b, then the mocking will fail and the original, non-mocked foo function is getting called inside the function bar:
from b import foo

def bar():
    foo()

Why the function foo is not mocked properly in the test when it's imported with the from keyword in the a module?

A module is an object like most things in python. import b is a reference to module b, so patching b.foo updates modifies the b module object. from b import foo copies the function reference from b.py at import time, and no longer has reference to the module. Now patching b.foo updates the value in the module, but a.py isn't referencing the module, so it does not get updated.

A way to avoid this is to have some proxy method, def foo(): _foo() where _foo has the actual implementation. This way you can import foo however you want and mock the internal b._foo to get consistent results. In my opinion tho (others may disagree), mock.patch is code-smell. Inject behavior via argument passing and composition, so you can test without needing patching at all. Patching has so many quirks and overall makes tests extremely brittle to refactoring.

First version of the script a.py
The code of a.py in your first version is:
import b

def bar():
    b.foo()

In the namespace of the script a.py there is the name b that points to the module b.py where is defined foo(). So in the file a.py the name b.foo points to the foo defined in b.py.
Your file test_a.py, by the instruction:
with mock.patch('b.foo') as mock_foo:

change the object pointed by b.foo from the function foo defined in b.py to the Mock object mock_foo and when bar() defined in a.py calls b.foo() is executed mock_foo and the test passes.
Second version of the script a.py
The code of a.py in your second version is:
from b import foo

def bar():
    foo()

so in this case the name foo is defined directly in a.py and it points to the function foo defined in b.py.
To change correctly the object pointed by the name foo defined in a.py in this case it is necessary to use the following file test_a.py:
from a import bar
from unittest import mock

def test_bar():
    with mock.patch('a.foo') as mock_foo:
        bar()
        mock_foo.assert_called_once()

In the previous code I have only changed the patch() as following:
 with mock.patch('a.foo') as mock_foo:

instead of:
 with mock.patch('b.foo') as mock_foo:

In this way the test passes.

The following are posts about the same topic:

Pay attention to mock in the right place

Where to patch



Without changing either module, you can patch a.b.foo instead of b.foo.

@chepner Thank you but if I try with with mock.patch('a.b.foo') as mock_foo: at the place of with mock.patch('b.foo') as mock_foo: and execute the test I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.b'; 'a' is not a package.

Does it work if you import a instead of from a import bar? (Too lazy to check myself; I don't know if patch can distinguish between a package a with a module b and some name a with a module-valued attribute b.)

@chepner If I add the instruction import a in the file test_a.py, the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.b'; 'a' is not a package remains.

OK, that's the issue I overlooked. The solution is to use patch.object, so that you can patch an attribute of the module a. Import a, then patch the name foo defined by the object referenced by a.b: patch.object(a.b, 'foo')

Good. Your solution works for the first version of the file a.py proposed by the OP. But it doesn't work for the second version of the file a.py proposed by the OP. For that version I have to use the instruction with mock.patch('a.foo') as mock_foo: write in my answer or the instruction with mock.patch.object(a, 'foo') as mock_foo: near to your suggestion.
